# POST request working on Postman but not on JS

Tags: node.js, post, axios, node-request

Been trying for a couple of days but can't get this request to work on NodeJS, used several request modules (axios, request, node-fetch) but the returned body is **blank**, same goes for postman if raw option is not selected for body.

Here is how I need to format the body on postman for the request to work:

[image: postman request]

And this is my last iteration of the request, using node-fetch:

```
    const rawResponse = await fetch(
        urlRenfe,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Cookie": cookie,
                "Referer": "https://venta.renfe.com/vol/infoPuntualidadTrenes.do",
                "Accept": "*/*",
            },
            body: `callCount=1
            windowName=
            c0-scriptName=infoPuntualidadTrenesSvcAjax
            c0-methodName=getInfoPuntualidadTrenes
            c0-id=0
            c0-e1=string:71500
            c0-e2=string:X7090115
            c0-param0=Object_Object:{cdgoEstacion:reference:c0-e1, terminal:reference:c0-e2}
            batchId=1
            instanceId=1
            page=%2Fvol%2FinfoPuntualidadTrenes.do
            scriptSessionId=6ngaztWVMGx8q6B16ABXAlLU1Om/LwA22Om-u7tpxIlXl`
        }
    );

    const response = await rawResponse.text();
```

I know 100% the headers, url and method are ok, it has to be the body, either on the library or my configuration for it.

Thanks a lot if you give me a hint on how to solve this.

Comment: @SandeepPatel no errors, body response is ok, but is empty, same case if the body is sent badly on postman

Comment: Body in JS contains whitespace at the beginning of every line except the first one. Can this be the issue?

Comment: @YuryFedorov it isn't already added one to test